# Searching for multiple facetsValues in Algolia

Tags: javascript, algolia

I have an array of Facet Values that I need to gather from an Algolia Indices. 
For example, these are: "Beds", "Occupancy". and "Floor".

At the moment, i've got the below code which will go to my Algolia Table, grab me all of the possible values for each of the above but I have to do a query into Algolia for each one. This results in 3 network calls to Algolia.

```
index.searchForFacetValues(
{
   facetName: val,
   facetQuery: "",
   maxFacetHits: 100,
   query: "2019"
},
function(err, content) {
   return content
})
```

Is there a way that I can get all the facet values for "Beds", "Occupancy". and "Floor" in a single query resulting in only one network call?

Also, i'm using https://www.algolia.com/doc/api-client/getting-started/install/javascript/

Answer (score 0):

You can use an empty search and specify which facets you want to receive values for:

```
client.search({ 
  query: '',
  facets: ['Beds', 'Occupancy', 'Floor'],
  attributesToRetrieve: [],  // a little optimisation for response transfer speed
});
```

The response will contain something like this:

```
{
  "facets": {
    "Beds": {
      "2": 1245,
      "4": 893,
      ...
    },
    "Floor": {
      ...
    },
    ...
  }
}
```

So the first level of keys in `facets` are your facet names, and within each nested facet object you have one key/value per facet value/hits count.

If you don't know in advance the list of facet names you want to get, use `facets: '*'` in your query parameters.